# Error compiling private.hpp OpenCV 3.0.0-rc1

Tags: c++, qt, opencv, opencv3.0

I downloaded OpenCV 3.0.0-rc1 and build it using CMAKE-gui 3.2.2 using VS2012 Win64 compiler. Binaries and libraries got generated and I set it up with Qt 64 bit. All programs are working fine except when I try to use the feature `cv::LineSegmentDetector` it shows a compile error in **private.hpp** file. The error says

```
unexpected end-of-line
```

My code is as follows

```
#include <opencv2/core/core.hpp>
#include <opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>
#include <opencv2/imgcodecs/imgcodecs.hpp>
#include <opencv2/features2d/features2d.hpp>
#include <opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp>
#include <opencv2/core/private.hpp>
#include <opencv2/core/utility.hpp>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    cv::Mat image = cv::imread("C:\\Users\\IMAGE\\Desktop\\PROJ\\SAMPLE.png");
    cv::imshow("TEST",image);
    cv::waitKey();

    cv::LineSegmentDetector lsd;

    return 0;
}
```

And on following the error I found the 2nd line of the following part of the code in private.hpp as error highlighted.

```
#ifdef HAVE_EIGEN
#  if defined __GNUC__ && defined __APPLE__
#    pragma GCC diagnostic ignored "-Wshadow"
#  endif
#  include <Eigen/Core>
#  include "opencv2/core/eigen.hpp"
#endif
```

**#  if defined __GNUC__ && defined __APPLE__**

Please let me know if I am doing some implementation mistake or some changes in the private.hpp can fix this error. I am using windows 8 64 bit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

oh, never try to use something, that is called "private", i guess...

```
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>       // includes all others
#include <opencv2/core/utility.hpp> // getTickCount, etc.

int main()
{
    // LineSegmentDetector is an abstract class, you can't create an
    // instance on the stack, but need to use Ptr and factory:
    cv::Ptr<cv::LineSegmentDetector> lsd = cv::createLineSegmentDetector();
    return 0;
}
```